# trailing and leading blank issue in string

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am working on a project where I need to check if the employee enter `*done*` in a text field, though employee enters '`* done *`' or '`*done *`' or '`* done*`' in similar fashion. As you see they are putting trailing and leading blank or both at a time.I have to check the column for all three/four possible entry in like statement, I tried trim,rtrim nothing seems like working.

```
 case when
col like ('*done*')
or col like ('* done*')
or col like ('*done *')
or col like ('* done *')
end as work_status
```

doesn't seems a smart way to do it. What is the best way to to check this. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces:

```
case when replace(col, ' ') = '*done*' then 'done'
     else 'not'
end as work_status
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the `done` substring with anything preceding and following using the `LIKE` operator and `%` wildcards:

```sql
CASE WHEN col LIKE '%done%' THEN 'done' END AS work_status
```

Or you can trim the leading and trailing space characters:

```sql
CASE WHEN TRIM(col) = 'done' THEN 'done' END AS work_status
```

Or you can replace all the leading/trailing white spaces (in case the users have entered new lines, tabs, etc. rather than space characters) using a regular expression:

```sql
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$') = 'done'
THEN 'done'
END AS work_status
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3MdSDEtF)

Comment: rtrim, REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+^') not removing space, not working

Comment: @deepankarsrigyan Fixed the typo with the regular expression and added a fiddle showing it working.

Comment: All of the options are giving me false positive. Is there something we can do about